# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] differs between 2 servers

Tags: php

I've got 2 servers from where I get my client `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

On server (A), I store the ip from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in the DB and perform a `header('Location: ...')` to Server (B).
Server (B), prints/echo the ip with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` on screen.

Sidenote: the page on server (A) gets called from inside an iframe, the page of server (B) gets loaded into the same iframe afterwards.

However when I compare both results, I can see that Server (A) returns the local network IP and Server (B) returns the external IP. What is the reason for this? I expected both to be the local/external ip as behavior.

Comment: What's a remote local IP?

Comment: Perhaps Server B is on your local subnet, while Server A is not? I.e. there is a local route to Server B (e.g. 10.0.1.2) even though you are accessing it through a global hostname (e.g. myhost.com). In some cases I think your networking hardware might route you through to the local IP. Also check the canonical host name settings of your web server.

Comment: Maybe there is a local reverse proxy in front of the webserver. In this case you can check if the reverse proxy sends a special Header with the client ip.

Comment: @Jack the external ip of the client

Comment: @Simon server A is also in the same subnet as the client, I think that might be it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the php manual:

> $_SERVER is an array containing information such as headers, paths,
>   and script locations. The entries in this array are created by the web
>   server. **There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any
>   of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here.**
>   That said, a large number of these variables are accounted for in the
>   » CGI/1.1 specification, so you should be able to expect those.

It's possible that your server A doesn't allow the get the remote ip adress for security reasons.